# netTCPBinding, wsHttpBinding behind the scenes

Tags: .net, wcf, networking

I am new to the world of Networking and hence a bit confused about how things work behind the scenes. This is important for me to decide which binding to choose for my service. I am under the impression that communication on the Network mainly happens through TCP/IP protocol. I went through the TCP/IP protocol and according to my understanding, HTTP is an application Layer protocol. Behind the scenes the application layer communicates with the Transport Layer which passes the information over the network using the TCP or the UDP protocol. If this is the case what would be the use of HTTP protocol? I am sure there is something missing in the puzzle but I am not able to find out what is it?

Answer (score 0):

WCF supports 4 transport protocols - HTTP, TCP, MSMQ and Named Pipes.

Suggest reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx) MSDN Magazine article and this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) post for further understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the W3C answered [Why a new protocol?](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/WhyHTTP.html) back in 1991. Though they basically said it is not Mail, File transfer, News, or Search.

I get the feeling, though, that your question is why use wsHttpBinding, as underneath it is all TCP anyway.  Microsoft's netTCPBinding is a Microsoft proprietary protocol. It is intended to be used when C# is on both ends of the pipe, additionally it is primarily targeted to when the development of both ends will be managed by a single entity, be that a single developer, team, or corporate conglomerate.  Because getting the data types right can be tricky. In the **Remarks** on the [NetTcpBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) we find that:

> This binding is an appropriate Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   system-provided choice for communicating over an Intranet.
>
> The default configuration for the NetTcpBinding is faster than the
>   configuration provided by the WSHttpBinding, but it is intended only
>   for WCF-to-WCF communication.

In contrast the wsHttpBinding was designed with interoperability in mind.  It conforms, at least somewhat, to existing web service standards. From the **Remarks** on the [WSHttpBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.aspx):

> The WSHttpBinding is similar to the BasicHttpBinding but provides more
>   Web service features. It uses the HTTP transport and provides message
>   security, as does BasicHttpBinding, but it also provides transactions,
>   reliable messaging, and WS-Addressing, either enabled by default or
>   available through a single control setting.

Most of those additional features listed are part of the modern [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) stack.

Finally, for those who would instead invent their protocol this article answers [Why [you should use] HTTP?](http://timothyfitz.com/2009/02/12/why-http/) instead.